# 'Parameters' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, .net

.NET 5, ASP.NET Core MVC

I was defined a namespace with a type:

```cs
namespace Company.Services
{
    public class APIService
    {
        // Some code here.
    }
}
```

Then I defined other 2 classes in the `APIService`:

```cs
namespace Company.Services
{
    public class APIService
    {
        // Some code here.
        public class APIObject{}
        public class Parameters{}
    }
}
```

Then I defined a method and try to instantiate these 2 classes:

```cs
namespace Company.Services
{
    public class APIService
    {
        // Some code here.
        public class APIObject{}
        public class Parameters{}
        public static APIObject[] Initialize(string strAPIS)
        {
            APIObject[] objs;
            Parameters params; // Threw error here.
        }
    }
}
```

Then the complier threw an error: `'Parameters' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context`, but the `APIObject` had no error.

I don't know what happened.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) is a C# keyword, and as such can't be used as a variable name.

You should either call your variable `@params`, or perhaps give it a different name altogether (maybe `parameters`)?

Comment: For future reference, this sort of error can be easily detected/avoided if you pay attention to syntax highlighting.

Comment: @JohnWu The syntax highlighting is correct in Visual Studio Code, so I didn't notice that... And I've never used this keyword. Thanks for your help